# Set email as username in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django

I am reading the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

So in my settings.py I put:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'membership.User'
```

And in my membership app models.py I have this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Running python manage.py syncdb is giving me:

```
FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'email'
```

I check AbstractBaseUser class source and the field is defined of course, as you can see here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L359

What's wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AbstractBaseUser` doesn't have email field, the `AbstractUser` does.

If you want to use email as a unique identifier, then you need to subclass from AbstractBaseUser and define email field with `unique=True` and also write other functionality, for example `Manager` of the model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager,\
    PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.pk)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    # define here other needed methods
    # Look at django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser
```

Also, you'll probably want to add this user to admin page. Look at [UserAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L36) and redefine it to be compatible with new user model, that use email field as unique identifier.

Comment: I am getting "FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'" after inheriting from AbstractUser.

Comment: Updated the answer. First i just mention, that AbstractBaseUser don't have email field, but it was written in question, that it does.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's nothing within `django.contrib.auth` that you can simply subclass to get a model that has

1. email address in place of user name and
2. works nicely with other `django.contrib.auth`-stuff, like groups.

The simplest approach is to copy `models.py`, `admin.py` and `forms.py` from `django.contrib.auth`, rip out user name all over the place and put in email address in it's place. I've done just that and I'm using it successfully in a couple of client projects.

I've put it up on github and pypi so you can install it with

```
pip install django-libtech-emailuser
```

and check the [usage instructions on github](https://github.com/Liberationtech/django-libtech-emailuser)

Comment: Works great in Django 1.5.  I installed your app with the instructions you have on github, and then just replaced any instance in my project of `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` with `from emailuser.models import EmailUser` and any reference of `User` with `EmailUser`.  Not sure why the common practice of using an email for a username would be anything but trivial for Django, but it is, even with these new features in 1.5.  Thanks for sharing.